# CoreStore map relationships while importing unique objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5, corestore

I found as I suppose good library [CoreStore](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CoreStore#importing-data) as we see they provide import and unique import with mapping functionality behind importable protocols which we need to implement in `NSManagedObject` object subclass to be able set properties.

My question is there documentation how to map relationships correctly? For example if I have one `Person` and many Addresses do I need to use the same didInsert func of Person NSManagedObject and perform async transaction like this:

```
func didInsert(from source: ImportSource, in transaction: BaseDataTransaction) throws {

let addresses = source["addresses"] as? [[String: Any]] // array of dict.

for address in addresses {
CoreStore.perform(
    asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Void in
        let json: [String: Any] = // ...
        try! transaction.importUniqueObject(
            Into<AddressEntity>(),
            source: address
        )
        // ...
    },
    completion: { _ in }
)
}

}
```

Do I need to do it async or sync and other question how then trigger even that all relationships are imported or CoreStore does it automatically or maybe I am on a wrong way and there is some another beautiful solution.

Thanks

As Martin suggested I have added something similar:

```
if let addressesJsonArray = source["addresses"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            let addresses = try transaction.importUniqueObjects(Into<Address>(), sourceArray: addressesJsonArray)

            let convertToSet = Set(addresses.map { $0 })

            self.phases = convertToSet
        }
```

Looks like it work for me, but .= throws:

```
Binary operator '.=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Set<AddressEntity>' and '[AddressEntity]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already run importUniqueObjects in a perform async block (hopefully), you don't have to worry about creating another async transaction to import and add the relationship. Just use the transaction that you have in your parameter.

You would rather want to do this in update(from source: ImportSource, in transaction: BaseDataTransaction) than in didInsert, or your relationships could break once you change something on the object.

You don't even have to loop, just use it like that, supposed that "addresses" is your relationship container:

```
func update(from source: ImportSource, in transaction: BaseDataTransaction) throws {
    if let addressesJsonArray = source["addresses"] as? [[String: Any]] { // array of dict.
        addresses .= try transaction.importUniqueObjects(Into<AddressEntity>(), sourceArray: addressesJsonArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: .= is some binary operator or this is just small mistake. also as I understood transaction.importUniqueObjects returns array and I need to convert it to set

Comment: The .= is a custom operator to be used with Value/Relationship containers that corestore provides for CoreStoreObject

Comment: are you sure) I have not found any info about it in the doc just in demo project as AssignmentPrecedence infix operator, but still don't know how to use, compiler throws error when I try to do it in my didInsert func.

Comment: The .= operator is just a shorthand for
attribute.value = object
But that only works if you use Value or Relationship containers, in your case something like: let addresses = Relationship.ToManyOrdered<AddressEntity>("addresses", inverse: { $0.person }) - with AddressEntity having the inverse relationship declared.

Comment: seems I need to investigate .= more as I still has not got idea how to use and my code can't be run when I use .=  , but anyway thanks for helpful comments

Comment: Binary operator '.=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Set<AddressEntity>' and '[AddressEntity]'

does it mean that I need to declare array instead of Set in NSManagedObject?

Comment: You are apparently not using CoreStoreObject to get the .= operator to work. Sorry for the inconvenience in the example. I saw you already figured out how to get a Set from an array.